How is $(p,v)$ used to calculate loss in the AlphaZero algorithm?
I'm trying to implement the AlphaZero algorithm. AlphaZero uses a neural
network $f_{\theta}$ with parameters $\theta$ for board state $s$. It
returns $(p,v)$, where $p$ is a vector of move probabilities and $v$ is
the predicted outcome.
As far as I know, this is the algorithm:

Initialize random parameters $\theta$.

Generate a lot of self-play games. For every decision in each game,
the bot should use MCTS, but instead of rollouts, it uses
$f_{\theta}$ as a policy value.

Train $f_{\theta}$ with back-propagation on the games, minimizing
the loss function.

Repeat steps 2-3 with the new $f_{\theta}$ until the bot is
sufficiently strong.


I want to understand step 3 better. This is AlphaZero's loss
function: $$(z - v)^{2} - \mathbf{\pi}^{T}\log p + c\|\theta\|^{2}$$
My belief is that $p$ and $v$ are based on one board state, while a
game may have many board states (one for each player's move). But one
back-propagation step should have the entire game as an input, not
just one board state, right? So how are the resulting $p$ and $v$ values
calculated? Do we take just one board state? Or do we average all of
them, or take random board states from the game and then average them?
Or something else?

Oh, I think it's the sum of all losses across board states, like the sum in MSE

The training does not involve processing entire game as input at once. Instead, it processes individual board states sampled from all self-play games. Training on individual states, rather than averaging over a game, aligns better with the loss function and facilitates efficient optimization using SGD.
